# Can't set Response Content-Type text/event-stream for Controller Action in .Net 6 WebAPI

Tags: .net, content-type, server-sent-events

I use **.Net 6 WebAPI**.

I want to create an action in a controller that is going to be used from client javascript [**Server Sent Events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) creating a **EventSource**(*urlToControllerActionGoesHere*).

My action I have tried with looks like below, but client immideately get 406 status back, and response code is "text/html" but it should be "text/event-stream" so probably that's why?

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("/sse")]
    [Produces("text/event-stream")]
    public async Task SSEMessage() //Continously write to response as Javascript Server Sent Event listeners get this data
    {
        do
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            //HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{data: Controller at {DateTime.Now}}}");
            await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        } while (true);
    }
```

**Client code looks like this:**

```
const serverSentEvents = new window.EventSource('http://localhost/mycontroller/sse', { withCredentials: true })
serverSentEvents.onmessage = e => {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.data)
  console.log('New server data:', data.item)
}

serverSentEvents.onerror = err => {
  console.log('EventSource failed.', err)
  serverSentEvents.close()
}
```

**So what am I doing wrong that Content-Type is not set to "text/event-stream"?**